# How to link and update input boxes by a inked selection index?

Tags: php, jquery, input, html-select

How can the input boxes values get linked to the selection with the if value?
In the following code, JQuery is taking the wrong index for each select option that should only update text inside it's own linked input boxes. Help is much appreciated!

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

$("select[name='item[]']").change(function() {

    // Link per each Item selection and its value base on if, to the input boxes, based on the index

    if ($(this).val() === 'None') {
         $("input[name='fee[]']").eq($(this).index("select")).val('0');
        }

    if ($(this).val() === 'Boots') {
         $("input[name='fee[]']").eq($(this).index("select")).val('125');
        }

    if ($(this).val() === 'Poles') {
         $("input[name='fee[]']").eq($(this).index("select")).val('150');
        }

    if ($(this).val() === 'Helmet') {
         $("input[name='fee[]']").eq($(this).index("select")).val('175');
        }

    if ($(this).val() === 'Jacket') {
         $("input[name='fee[]']").eq($(this).index("select")).val('275');
        }

    if ($(this).val() === 'Gloves') {
         $("input[name='fee[]']").eq($(this).index("select")).val('75');
        }

    if ($(this).val() === 'Mittens') {
         $("input[name='fee[]']").eq($(this).index("select")).val('85');
        }
    }).change()

    // Debugging : change bgcolor on hover
    $("select[name='item[]']").hover(function() {
        $("input[name='fee[]']").eq($(this).index("select")).css("background","#a6955d");
        }, function() {
        $("input[name='fee[]']").eq($(this).index("select")).css("background","white");
    });


$("select[name='duration[]']").change(function() {

    // Link per each Item Duratin selection and its value base on if, to the input boxes, based on the index

    if ($(this).val() === '0') {
         $("input[name='time[]']").eq($(this).index("select")).val('0');
        }

    if ($(this).val() === '1') {
         $("input[name='time[]']").eq($(this).index("select")).val('1');
        }

    if ($(this).val() === '2') {
         $("input[name='time[]']").eq($(this).index("select")).val('2');
        }

    if ($(this).val() === '3') {
         $("input[name='time[]']").eq($(this).index("select")).val('3');
        }
    }).change()

    // Debugging : change bgcolor on hover
    $("select[name='duration[]']").hover(function() {
        $("input[name='time[]']").eq($(this).index("select")).css("background","#a6955d");
        }, function() {
        $("input[name='time[]']").eq($(this).index("select")).css("background","white");
    });

}); 
</script>

</head>
<body>
<h1 style="align:middle;">Welcome to Mountain Ski Resort</h1>
<form method="post">
<table border="1">
<tr><thead><th>Row ID</th>
<th>Item</th>
<th>Fee</th>
<th colspan="2">Duratin</th>
</thead>
</tr>

<?php
// Create the form with Selections and Input rows
 for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){
?>
<tr>
<td align="right"><?php echo $i ?></td>
<td>
<select name="item[]">
<option value='None' selected>Select Item</option>
<option value='Boots'>Boots</option>
<option value='Poles'>Poles</option>
<option value='Helmet'>Helmet</option>
<option value='Jacket'>Jacket</option>
<option value='Gloves'>Gloves</option>
<option value='Mittens'>Mittens</option>
</select></td>
<td><input name="fee[]" size="10" readonly></td>
<td>
<select name="duration[]">
<option value='0' selected>Select Duration</option>
<option value='1'>One Hour</option>
<option value='2'>Two Hours</option>
<option value='3'>Three Hours</option>
</select></td>
<td><input name="time[]" size="10" readonly></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>

<tr><td colspan="5" align="middle"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td></tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php

//  Echo the submitted data to view

echo '<h2>Submitted data:</h2>';

echo '<table border="1">
<tr><thead><th>Row ID</th>
<th>Item</th>
<th>Fee</th>
<th colspan="2">Duration</th>
<th>Total</th>
</thead>
</tr>';

for ($i=0;$i < count($_POST['item']);$i++){

$row=$i+1;

// Calculate Totals based on fees multiplied by duration
$fee = $_POST['fee'][$i];
$duration = $_POST['duration'][$i];
$total = $fee * $duration; 

// Format outputs
$fee_formatted = '$' . number_format(intval($fee), 2, '.', ',');
$total_formatted = '$' . number_format($total, 2, '.', ',');
$duration_formatted = $duration . ':00';

// Output all data submitted and calculation into a table to view
echo '<tr>
<td align="right">' . $row .
'</td><td>' . $_POST['item'][$i] .
'</td><td align="right">' . $fee_formatted .
'</td><td colspan="2" align="right">' . $duration_formatted .
'</td><td align="right">' . $total_formatted .
'</td></tr>';
}

echo '</table>';

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fully functional simple demo solution I managed to put together for anyone interested in the same issue. It demonstrates a "Ski Resort" with "Renting Equipment". It uses `JavaScript` to link `Select Options` values to the `Text Inputs` value and calculates including output of numbers to words. Comments and suggestion are most welcome.

```
<?php
// Numbers to Words basic
$words = array('0'=> '' ,'1'=> 'one' ,'2'=> 'two' ,'3' => 'three',
'4' => 'four','5' => 'five','6' => 'six','7' => 'seven','8' => 'eight',
'9' => 'nine','10' => 'ten','11' => 'eleven','12' => 'twelve','13' => 'thirteen',
'14' => 'fourteen','15' => 'fifteen','16' => 'sixteen','17' => 'seventeen',
'18' => 'eighteen','19' => 'nineteen','20' => 'twenty','30' => 'thirty','40' => 'forty',
'50' => 'fifty','60' => 'sixty','70' => 'seventy','80' => 'eighty','90' => 'ninety','100' => 'hundred',
'1000' => 'thousand','100000' => 'hundred thousand','10000000' => 'ten million');

function NumWords($num)
{    
    global $words;

    if($num == 0){

        return '';

        } else {        

        $NumValue='';
        $HighNum=$num;
        $RemainNum=0;
        $valueHundred=100;
        $valueThousand=1000;

            while($num>=100)    {

                if(($valueHundred <= $num) &&($num  < $valueThousand))    {
                    $NumValue=$words["$valueHundred"];
                    $HighNum = (int)($num/$valueHundred);
                    $RemainNum = $num % $valueHundred;
                    break;
                }
                    $valueHundred= $valueThousand;
                    $valueThousand = $valueHundred * 100;
                }       

          if(array_key_exists("$HighNum",$words)){
              return $words["$HighNum"]." ".$NumValue." ".NumWords($RemainNum);
         } else {
             $unit=$HighNum%10;
             $ten =(int)($HighNum/10)*10;            
             return $words["$ten"]." ".$words["$unit"]." ".$NumValue." ".NumWords($RemainNum);
           }
    }
}
?>

<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

        // To link per index, get value per selection index and set value per input index (Item to Fee)
        function itemAmount(){

        objitem = document.getElementsByName("item[]"); // Array of elements named Items
        objfee = document.getElementsByName("fee[]"); // Array of elements named Fees

        for (var i = 0; i < objitem.length; i++) {

                selindex = objitem[i].options[objitem[i].selectedIndex]; // Get the current selected option index

                // Following lines will get values per index of selection and set the value we assign, 
                // to the input with the same index

                if(selindex.value=='None'){ 
                objfee[i].value = '0';
                }

                if(selindex.value=='Boots'){
                objfee[i].value = '125';
                }

                if(selindex.value=='Poles'){
                objfee[i].value = '150';            
                }

                if(selindex.value=='Helmet'){
                objfee[i].value = '175';
                }

                if(selindex.value=='Jacket'){
                objfee[i].value = '200';
                }               

                if(selindex.value=='Gloves'){
                objfee[i].value = '75';
                }               

                if(selindex.value=='Mittens'){
                objfee[i].value = '115';
                }               

            }

        }

        // To link per index, get value per selection index and set value per input index (Duration to Time)
        function durationTime(){

        objduration = document.getElementsByName("duration[]");
        objtime = document.getElementsByName("time[]");

        for (var i = 0; i < objduration.length; i++) {

                selindex = objduration[i].options[objduration[i].selectedIndex];
                objtime[i].value = selindex.value;


            }

        }

</script>

</head>
<body>
<center>
<h1>Welcome to Mountain Ski Resort</h1>
<form method="post">
<fieldset style="width: 200px; height: 400px;">
  <legend>Equipment Rentals</legend>
<table border="1">
<tr><thead><th>Row ID</th>
<th>Item</th>
<th>Fee</th>
<th colspan="2">Duration</th>
</thead>
</tr>
<?php
// Create the form with 10 Rows of Selections and Input - Can be decreased/increased to any desired number
 for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){
?>
<tr>
<td align="right"><?php echo $i ?></td>
<td>
<select name="item[]" onchange="itemAmount()">
<option value='None' selected>Select Item</option>
<option value='Boots'>Boots</option>
<option value='Poles'>Poles</option>
<option value='Helmet'>Helmet</option>
<option value='Jacket'>Jacket</option>
<option value='Gloves'>Gloves</option>
<option value='Mittens'>Mittens</option>
</select></td>
<td><input name="fee[]" size="10" value="0" readonly></td>
<td>
<select name="duration[]" onchange="durationTime()">
<option value='0' selected>Select Duration</option>
<option value='1'>One Hour</option>
<option value='2'>Two Hours</option>
<option value='3'>Three Hours</option>
</select></td>
<td><input name="time[]" size="10" value="0" readonly></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>

<tr><td colspan="5" align="middle"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td></tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
</form>

<?php

//  Echo the submitted data to view

echo '<fieldset style="width: 300px;">
 <legend>Submitted data</legend>
<table border="1">
<tr><thead><th>Row ID</th>
<th>Item</th>
<th>Fee</th>
<th colspan="2">Duration</th>
<th>Total</th>
</thead>
</tr>';

$grandTotal = 0;

for ($i=0;$i < count($_POST['item']);$i++){

$row=$i+1;

// Calculate Row Totals based on fees multiplied by duration
$fee = $_POST['fee'][$i];
$duration = $_POST['duration'][$i];
$total = $fee * $duration;

// Addup Totals Column for a Grand Total
$grandTotal += $total;

// Format outputs
$fee_formatted = '$' . number_format(intval($fee), 2, '.', ',');
$total_formatted = '$' . number_format($total, 2, '.', ',');
$duration_formatted = $duration . ':00';
$grandTotal_formatted =  '$' . number_format($grandTotal, 2, '.', ',');

// Output all data submitted and calculation into a table to view
echo '<tr>
<td align="right">' . $row .
'</td><td>' . $_POST['item'][$i] .
'</td><td align="right">' . $fee_formatted .
'</td><td colspan="2" align="right">' . $duration_formatted .
'</td><td align="right">' . $total_formatted .
'</td></tr>';

}

echo '<tr><td colspan="5">Grand Total US$:&nbsp;' . NumWords($grandTotal) . '</td>' .
'<td align="right">'. $grandTotal_formatted .'</td></tr>';

echo '</table></fieldset>';

?>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```